# Angular 2 typescript Unicode(Arabic) text support

Tags: typescript, angular

I having trouble while using typescript and Angular 2 
it was working fine like this :
[image]

but when adding Unicode text "arabic" i'm getting this 
[image]
[image]

The html file is fine stand-alone   but after compinge 
[image]

My TypeScript config file `tsconfig.json`

```ts
            {
              "compilerOptions": {
                "module": "commonjs",
                "target": "es5",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "noLib": false
              },
              "exclude": [
                  "node_modules"
              ]
            }
```

--
Help , Any idea : 
I tried google and the Anglular docs !

Comment: Do you use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`? Did you save your file in UTF8 encoding? See also http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Comment: the **js file** that the typescript compiler output is  is changing every Unicode letter to => **uFFFD**

Comment: that seems to be the desired behviour. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an Angular issue.

See also 
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6036

There seems to be a pull request for a similar case. Not sure if this fixes your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

`jspdf` not supported arabic characters in `angular2`. I use `jspdf` in `angular2` and try to insert arabic characters,i add a font
but don't work

```
doc.addFont('NafeesNastaleeq.ttf', 'arabic', 'normal', 'Identity-H');
doc.setFont('arabic');
doc.text(50, 50, 'السلام عليكم'  );
```